# Object doesn't support property or method 'Toggle' in IE9 and IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting JavaScript error like:

> Object doesn't support property or method 'Toggle'

The `slideToggle` is working fine in IE. But i am getting this JavaScript error in IE. How can I resolve this. need to add any plugin or change anything.

```
 $('#divid').slideToggle("slow");
 $('#divid').Toggle("slow");
```

Comment: Try `toggle()` in lowercase.

Answer (score 7):

Replace

```
$('#divid').Toggle("slow");
```

with

```
$('#divid').toggle("slow");
```

Javascript is case-sensitive.

Comment: a nuance, but jquery is not *made* from js. jquery is a framework on top of js.

Comment: @Eonasdan +1 As I was disagreeing too, I rolled back this edit.

Answer (score 5):

Should be `$('#divid').toggle("slow");`

**all jQuery methods start with *lowercase*.**
*camelCase* is usually used when combining two (or more) terms

```
slideToggle()
```

or here an example from JavaScript:

```
toLowerCase()
```

Usually (not a rule) you can find the use of  *Uppercase* when naming JS Objects or variables referencing objects like e.g: `var Calculate = new Object();`