# BootstrapToggle throwing error on IE11

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-11

I have many users with IE11 using my code...(my solution is a Microsoft Word app, which unfortunately uses the IE11 engine when running on Windows machines so MSFT can support Windows 7 users...!!!).

One user is seeing a

> "Object doesn't support property or method 'bootstrapToggle'"

error...

Any reason why IE11 might not run/allow this library?

User is in another timezone and its been hard getting additional info...I've asked them to update IE11 etc. The rest of my basic bootstrap3, jquery app loads okay...

Comment: That error tells you the "bootstrapToggle" jQuery module did not load. You'll have to show us some more context to see why.

Comment: you might be missing the library itself which you need to include it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25602595/error-object-doesnt-support-property-or-method-popover-in-ie-9

Comment: or take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14215138/object-doesnt-support-property-or-method-toggle-in-ie9-and-ie8

Comment: Thanks guys! Agree need more info...but this code runs great on IE11 for zillions of users and myself...not clear why it's barfing for this one user. I can only guess IE11 needing updating or some security setting (but other JS libraries load...).